# Write to XML in ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, file

I am completely new to Ruby. All I want is to produce a simple XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<product>
   <name>Test</name>
</product>
```

That's it.

Comment: Well, there you have it - save it to a file :P

Comment: I meant, using an object model.

Answer (score 67):

Builder should probably be your first stopping point:

```
require 'builder'

def product_xml
  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new( :indent => 2 )
  xml.instruct! :xml, :encoding => "ASCII"
  xml.product do |p|
    p.name "Test"
  end
end

puts product_xml
```

produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<product>
  <name>Test</name>
</product>
```

which looks about right to me.

Some Builder references:

- [author's (Jim Weirich) original blog post](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BuilderObjects.rdoc)
- [API docs](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder)
- [article at XML.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/01/04/creating-xml-with-ruby-and-builder.html)

Comment: The API docs link seems to be dead (I think rubyforge.org itself is no more?). Is there an updated link available?

Comment: @pioto docs are available at https://github.com/jimweirich/builder -- I've proposed an edit fixing the link in the original post, but it's pending review.

Answer (score 24):

Simply with
[Nokogiri::XML::Builder](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder)

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.products {
      xml.widget {
        xml.id_ "10"
        xml.name "Awesome widget"
      }
    }
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

Will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <products>
    <widget>
      <id>10</id>
      <name>Awesome widget</name>
    </widget>
  </products>
</root>
```

Comment: This is probably the most simple example of Nokogiri I've seen yet. Awesome.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [builder](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder#project-builder) to generate xml.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple more options for constructing XML in Ruby

[REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) - built-in but is very slow especially when dealing with large documents

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/) - newer and faster, installs as a rubygem

[LibXML-Ruby](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/) - built on the C libxml library, also installs as a rubygem

If you can't install rubygems then REXML is your best options.  If you are going to be creating large complex XML docs then Nokogiri or LibXML-Ruby is what you would want to use.

Comment: All these are really for parsing existing xml, you should use Builder to create xml.

Comment: nokogiri got a [builder also](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html) - not sure if it is any better but if you are doing both parsing and writing it may be sweet to use the same lib.

Comment: Nokogiris builder seems focused on blocks. It does work but I've found Builder very helpful with building xml programatically