# User Input, UTF-8 and XML Support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, utf-8

I have a rails app that creates events. Users input their event details, and those details get saved in the database. Those records are then pulled by a cron job and put into an xml file for another application to use. I'm having issues with non UTF-8 characters and the "&" character. I have a validation using regex to detect the non UTF-8 characters, but it doesn't tell what is allowed, because it validates after the user has left the input field. Does anyone have any suggestion for stripping and replacing characters on multiple fields? Thanks!

Here is an example of the validation code I'm using:

```
<%= f.input :description, label: 'Event Description:' %>

validates_format_of :description, :with => /^[\000-\177]*$/, :allow_blank => true, :message => "Please remove all special characters"
```

This is just one of the many fields I need to validate (en masse) and show which characters are not allowed, or strip and replace the bad characters.I'm not sure if there is a gem that already does this or not, or maybe there is a simple way to do this via rails (other than writing those big validation strings, that don't show the user what character is the problem). Maybe this just plain isn't easy to do in Rails. I'm new so I'd love some feedback.

Thanks Stack!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an XML library/application to handle the following:

> Those records are then pulled by a cron job and put into an xml file
>   for another application to use

Otherwise you're going to have to cater for all the escapable XML entities and look after character encoding etc. The user should be able to enter these characters, and the XML creation mechanism will be able to escape these automatically.

As such, I *don't* think this is a validation issue.

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244255/write-to-xml-in-ruby) re. XML creation via Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are seeing "non-UTF-8" characters indicates not that your users are entering bad data, but that you are handling the input incorrectly.  If the input field is accepting CP-1252 (or ISO-8859-1) extended ASCII (characters between 0x80 and 0xFF), then the conversion to valid UTF-8 should be occurring at that point.

Every input character that you think is "invalid" is really still valid.  It is an ISO-8859-1 code point (bit pattern) representing a specific glyph *in that code page*.  That glyph has a corresponding Unicode code point *and* a valid UTF-8 encoding (a 2-byte sequence).  If you were to perform the conversion when taking the input from the user and before putting it in the XML, the problem would go away and the users could enter whatever they wanted and get the correct results.